# sort part of results one way part another

Tags: mongodb, sorting

Is there any way to get documents with one find operation sorted this way:
First documents where propertyA is true, sorted by propertyB descending.
Then documents where propertyA is false sorted by propertyC descending?

For example:

```
{ id:1, propA: false, propB: 1, propC: 4}
{ id:2, propA: false, propB: 2, propC: 1}
{ id:3, propA:  true, propB: 8, propC: 2}
{ id:4, propA: false, propB: 4, propC: 3}
{ id:5, propA:  true, propB: 7, propC: 5}
```

should be sorted this way:

```
{ id:3, propA:  true, propB: 8, propC: 2}
{ id:5, propA:  true, propB: 7, propC: 5}
{ id:1, propA: false, propB: 1, propC: 4}
{ id:4, propA: false, propB: 4, propC: 3}
{ id:2, propA: false, propB: 2, propC: 1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordinal sort is not enough but you can use aggregation framework to evaluate your second ordering property. [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) with [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) give you the possibility to add new field based on your condition. Entire operation looks like below:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    { 
        $addFields: {
            thenByProperty: {
                $cond: { if: "$propA", then: "$propB", else: "$propC" }
            }
        } 
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            propA: -1,
            thenByProperty: -1
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Nice, it worked, is there any way to create this field based on returning value of function execution, to code there some logic to analyze current document?

Comment: @Sol If you mean something like trigger in SQL then I'm afraid not. There are two ways I think: you can create that field in your business logic code or use aggregation just as I described

Comment: I mean something like this:
$addFields: {
            thenByProperty: {
                function(document) { return document.prop1+document.prop2 // or some other code}
            }
        }

Comment: No, you can't add your custom logic to pipeline stages, however there is a lot of operators which might be useful here. For instance if you want to add two other fileds you can use $add: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/